# Why is my view showing blank data in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to display data from my service in a table. I do get the data from the service but just not showing/visible in my view. I do not know what I am missing as this is working in another table that I did.

**Code in my component** of which is printing the list when i subscribe.

```
allMsgRecipients: Observable<MsgRecipient[]>;
allRecipients: MsgRecipient[];

loadAllMsgRecipients() {  
    this.allMsgRecipients = this.msgRecipientService.getAllMsgRecipient();
    this.msgRecipientService.getAllMsgRecipient().subscribe(recipients => {this.allRecipients = recipients as MsgRecipient[];
      console.log(this.allRecipients)} // this is coming back with data
      );
  }
```

**My view code**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center">
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Recipient Name</th>
          <th class="text-center">Cell No</th>
          <th class="text-center">Email</th>
          <th class="text-center">IsActive</th>
          <th class="text-center">Reporting Group</th>
          <th class="text-center">Additional Info</th>
          <th class="text-center">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let recipient of allMsgRecipients ">
          <td>
            <span (keyup)="changeValue(recipient.RecipientID, $event)" (blur)="updateList(recipient.RecipientID, 'RecipientName', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{recipient.RecipientName}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span contenteditable="true" ng-keyup="changeValue(recipient.RecipientID, $event)" (blur)="updateList(recipient.RecipientID, 'CellNo', $event)">{{recipient.CellNo}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span contenteditable="true" (keyup)="changeValue(recipient.RecipientID, $event)" (blur)="updateList(recipient.RecipientID, 'Email', $event)">{{recipient.Email}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span contenteditable="true" (keyup)="changeValue(recipient.RecipientID, $event)" (blur)="updateList(recipient.RecipientID, 'IsActive', $event)">{{recipient.IsActive}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span contenteditable="true" (keyup)="changeValue(recipient.RecipientID, $event)" (blur)="updateList(recipient.RecipientID, 'ReportingGroup', $event)">{{recipient.ReportingGroup}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
              <span contenteditable="true" (keyup)="changeValue(recipient.RecipientID, $event)" (blur)="updateList(recipient.RecipientID, 'AdditionalInfo', $event)">{{recipient.AdditionalInfo}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="table-remove">
              <button type="button" mdbBtn color="danger" rounded="true" size="sm" class="my-0" (click)="deleteMsgRecipient(recipient.RecipientID)">Remove</button>
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: did you try displaying the data in a normal div using ngFor ?

Comment: Is your component or any parent component set to the change detection strategy: `OnPush`

Comment: @PierreDuc No I do not have that

Comment: My table is showing empty rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out finally and thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Solution:

This is how my Json was coming back. first letter as lower case.

```
{
        "recipientID": 1,
        "recipientName": "Test",
        "cellNo": "12334",
        "email": "test@test.co.za",
        "isActive": false,
        "reportingGroup": "Sales",
        "additionalInfo": null
    }
```

But My properties in my class had first letter as upper case. So I just had to make the two match and it worked. Sucks to be new in something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'allMsgRecipients' (Because It's observable) then

```
...
<tr *ngFor="let recipient of ( allMsgRecipients | sync)">
...
```

If you are using 'allRecipients' then

```
...
<tr *ngFor="let recipient of allRecipients">
...
```

Let me know If you have ny query.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried both ways but still not displaying data. it frustrating because I am not getting any error

Comment: Console log printed correctly ? or Can u show me your complete .ts file ?